# Python terminal not showing code Output for simple Hello World

Tags: python

newbie Python user. My Hello World code was working yesterday but today it just stopped and I'm not sure why, attached below is a screenshot of what the terminal looks like after I run the code. It displays the directory just not the actual "Hello World" output.
[image: Python error image]

Comment: Please try to paste the code using code blocks in the future (surround it with triple ``` backquotes), instead of posting images, no matter how simple your code. This way people can also read your questions years from now were the image server to go down, as well as allowing them to test your code with a simple copy/paste. I don't see an error message in your IDE, by the way, but @Darshan V pointed out the problem.

Comment: Okay will definitely begin doing that thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 2):

Because you typed

```py
print = (message)
```

**instead of**

```py
print(message)
```

Comment: Never mind it happens !